# Azure Dashboard to show only service health

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-dashboard

Right now I'm limited to using only Azure dashboards for reporting on resources.  A dashboard I need to create is one where only the resource health of my resources is displayed the way it is displayed by going to Dashboard->Monitor->Service Health.  I need to be able to choose only my resource types and have them display in a nice list with a green arrow for up and that red X for down.  Is this possible to do from inside the portal?  It's imperative that those that use the dashboard do not have to click anything to see the healthy/unhealthy status.  I basically need the list below, but for all of my resources, not just AKS.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the answer, it's in preview.  Create a workbook and add a query.  In the query, choose "Azure Health (preview)", for the resource type choose "Subscription" and BOOM!, there it is.  This was easier than I thought, I just had to do some heavy digging.  I hope this helps other people trying to do this.  Oh, and I pinned this to a dashboard and everyone was thrilled.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! Please consider including a screenshot as well so it helps others having similar queries.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting ask indeed. AFAIK, pinning Azure Resource Health filtered by resource type to the Azure Dashboard is not supported as of today. Also, I noticed that the pin icon atop the page only creates a shortcut to Azure Service issues but not to the Resource Health blade.

You can submit your suggestion to the Azure Service Health Product Group through their [feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919477-azure-service-health), or upvote [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/919477-azure-service-health/suggestions/35997619-show-resource-health-in-the-dashboard) similar idea.